# How to fill the space between y_axis and a plot with python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

## I have 2 lists x and y. I have plotted the graph using matplotlib library.

## Actually, I would like to fill the space between the the graph and the y axis (x =0).

```
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
fig = Figure(figsize=(11, 45), dpi=300)

axes1 = fig.add_subplot(121)
axes2 = fig.add_subplot(122)

x = [10, 3, 15, -2, 25]
y= [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

z = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

axes1.fill_between(x, y, z, color='red', alpha=.5)
axes2.plot(x, y)

#axes1.invert_yaxis()
#axes2.invert_yaxis()

fig.savefig('Axis.png')
```

[I want to fill the right side graph as shown on the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqX6r.jpg)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to fill the area between the line x = 0 and the graph.

Comment: `axes2.fill_betweenx(y, x, 0, color='skyblue')` [docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.fill_betweenx.html)